# cost function for k mean clustering

Tags: scikit-learn, scikits

I am using sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans, for my dataset. I want to find " (1/number of samples)*( the summation of squared distance between x (i) 
and its cluster center)" which is shown in the following picture.

[image: Cost function]

There is an "inertia_" in "sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans".I was wondering "inertia_" is calculating this number? or is there any other way to find it.
thanks for your consideration.

Comment: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html#k-means
Looks like it is what you want. But you can just compute sum of squared distance between every point in training set and it's cluster center, to double check.

Answer (score 1):

That's correct. According to their documentation, they define `inertia` as

[image]

So to get the inertia from your estimator, grab `sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.inertia_`.